# Regular expression to select first N number of characters except a certain character

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a number of scripts in a directory which take the format of 120100_0019_0_X0434147_script_name.sql

I need to select the first 11 numbers only (excluding the underlines)

For the above script the result I need is 12010000190

I can get the result by using the following line but I was hoping someone could explain how I could achieve this result using a shorter code or with `sed` only.

```
echo "$SCRIPT" | cut -c 1-13 | sed 's/_//g'
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using a regular expression" since you already use a regular expression (with sed). And what is your goal? You already have a working code. Are you looking for a shorter code?

Comment: Yes apologies, I would like to see if I could shorten the code, or to see if there was a way to achieve this with sed alone

Answer (score 1):

bash only approach:

```
$ script=120100_0019_0_X0434147_script_name.sql

$ script1=${script//_/} # Remove all _
$ script1=${script1:0:11} #Take first 11 characters
$ echo $script1
12010000190
```

OR

```
$ script1=${script//_/} # Remove all _
$ script1=${script1/X*/} # Remove everything starting from X
$ echo $script1
12010000190
```

OR

```
$ script1=${script//_/} # Remove all _
$ script1=${script1/[^0-9]*/} # Remove everything starting from first non-numeric character.
$ echo $script1
12010000190
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
echo '120100_0019_0_X0434147_script_name.sql' | sed -r 's/_//g; s/(^[0-9]{11}).*/\1/'
```

which first remove the '_' then select the first 11 digits ignoring the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expression, you can write:

```
echo "${SCRIPT::13}" | tr -d _
```